# I've created a list in python but how do I iterate through this list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, json

I create a list in python and then have converted it to json.  But I'm having trouble iterating through this in javascript and displaying the correct items.

Any advice?

python:

```
def friends2(request):
    fb_feed = [#data in here]
    b = json.dumps(fb_feed)
    print b
    return HttpResponse(b)
```

what is printed in the console when I `print b`:

```
[
    [1236870349, "Your friend", "Bhangra indian Jingle Bells balle balle Merry Christmas", "2lPdXV1KO4s", "Your friend watched \"Bhangra indian Jingle Bells balle balle Merry Christmas\""], 
    [2303218, "Your friend", "Look at this Instagram (Nickelback Parody)", "ttp://www.c", "Your friend watched \"Look at this Instagram (Nickelback Parody)\""]

]
```

javascript

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function (){

            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                 type:"GET",
                 url:"/friends2/",
                 data: {},

                 success: function(b){
                    b = jQuery.parseJSON(b);
                                            console.log(b) //returns null
                    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { 
                            var friend = "";
                            friend = b[i][3]
                            friend += "\n";
                            $('.social').append(friend);
                        }                

                    }
            });
});
</script>
```

html

```
<div class = 'social'></div>
```

Comment: What does the full json look like? What do you want to be shown from the json?

Comment: What I showed above is what gets printed when I run print b so I believe it's the full contents.  I was a little confused though because it didn't look like JSON (no {} )...

Comment: There's no requirement for JSON to contain `{}`. JSON is a version of JS syntax: objects start with `{}`, arrays start with `[]`. You have a JSON representation of an array, which is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `dataType:json` to `$.ajax` script

```
 $.ajax({
         type:"GET",
         url:"/friends2/",  #the url /friends2/ points to friends2 in python
         data: {},
         dataType: json, //ADD THIS
         ...
         ...
```

If you don't want to add `dataType` then you can use `jQuery.parseJSON(b)` to parse your json string,

```
success: function(b) {
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(b); //parse JSON string here
    ...
    ...

}
```

Comment: I guess I also have a question if the variable 'b" that gets returned truly is JSON even though I have b = json.dumps(fb_feed).  When I print b, I don't see what I usually expect in a JSON variable such as the {} at the beginning and end.

Comment: @sharataka I think what you want is b.content

Comment: I edited my javascript but I'm still not getting anything displayed.

Comment: IT seems b is not getting through in the javascript when I check through console.log.

Comment: put `console.log` before `jQuery.parseJSON` and tell me what you see.

Comment: There are actually 9 elements in the list.  When I put it before parseJSON, I see [Array[5], Array[5], Array[5], Array[5], Array[5], Array[5], Array[5], Array[5], Array[5]]
0: Array[5]
1: Array[5]
2: Array[5]
3: Array[5]
4: Array[5]
5: Array[5]
6: Array[5]
7: Array[5]
8: Array[5]
length: 9
__proto__: Array[0]
 127.0.0.1:150
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null.  It seems to be getting the different attributes within the array.

Comment: I think `json.dumps(fb_feed)` returns array not JSON. Try to find a way to get as JSON

Comment: Any advice on how to do that?  OR can I just iterate through the array?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in your code. the json should be correct. b[3] is undefined, as the array is of length 2. did you mean b[i][3]?

everything else should work as far as i can tell.

Comment: I edited my javascript but I'm still not getting anything displayed.

Comment: perhaps you could try success: function(b){console.log(b)} to print the returned json file to your console. If this doesn't allow you to solve your problem perhaps posting the returned json up here would help others help you. Good luck!

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null.  IT seems b is not getting through in the javascript...

Answer (score 0):

If your view is returning JSON, you should set the content type (MIME type) accordingly:

```
return HttpResponse(b, content_type='application/json')
```

jQuery's `$.ajax` is smart enough to automatically apply `dataType: json` when the MIME type is set correctly:

> dataType
>
> Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is
> specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the
> response